# Attempted import error: 'Container' is not exported from 'react-bootstrap'

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

Error message:
Failed to compile.
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap' in 'D:\Study\React\projects\search-app\src'

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Jumbotron } from "react-bootstrap";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Jumbotron>
          <Container>
            <h1>Search App</h1>
            <p>This is a simple search app</p>
          </Container>
        </Jumbotron>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Are you sure you have it in your dependencies?

Comment: Hi, if you have the dependency, try running `npm install`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the right syntax of importing a component in react-bootstrap is the following :

```
import componentName from 'react-bootstrap/componentName '
```

so in your case you should do :

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
import Jumbotron from 'react-bootstrap/Jumbotron'
```

you could check [the official API](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/#grid-props)